# Default mirror when resizing

Tags: modeling

Every time I resize an object it resizes on both sides so mirrored resizing and I can't find why in the settings. This is a nightmare to deal with since I can't resize normally and I am forced to resize by moving the face which doesn't work for certain modifiers .

Answer (score 0):

If I followed your question correctly: In edit mode, the default scale method is "Individual Elements" which means the scale occurs centered on the selected, connected faces. In the following example, I cut a Suzanne in half and added a mirror modifier:
[image] You can see her eyeballs popped out and she gets strangely wide. I assume this is what your question is about... To "fix" this, set the 3D cursor to the center of the object (in this example, I left it at the default world origin) and set the scale method to "3D Cursor". This makes scale behave more like it intuitively should [image]

I didn't highlight the thing that changed... Look in the top center next to the word "Global"